# Email exceptions with stacktrace to dev team from application insights

Tags: .net, azure, email, logging, azure-application-insights

In our older parts of our systems we have setup logging so that the dev team receives emails when an exception is thrown. The newer parts of our systems are hosted in azure and log errors to application insights. I've looked into application insights alerts, the alerts that can be setup to send email does however does not contain any information about the exception, or possibility to filter exceptions that are irrelevant.

So, given all the APIs available, I think that it should be possible to create emails that are more detailed. Does anyone have any information about the subject?

I can imagine creating a timer trigger function in Azure that would poll application insights API for errors at some interval and send emails, but creating it from scratch is a bit of a threshold.

Comment: Are you looking to access the exception recorded to Application Insights AFTER your .NET code has detected the exception and recorded its occurrence via telemetry.TrackException(ex)? Then, you would like error emails generated on some scheduled basis as opposed to sending the email when the exception is first detected. Is that what you want?

Comment: If I'm a member of a dev team, I wanna receive exception information and its detail by email immediately, the 'detail' may contains exception code, exception message, belongs to which file, etc. And I really have created a rule for my java application, it will monitor the count of exception. And I can receive email like this. I think it can meet my requirement. Could you pls tell us which kind of 'detail' about the exception you require? https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEqOe.png

Comment: @JohnH: yes, you describe an implementation that would be a solution for my problem. As I would like to have the information about the exceptions as soon as possible it might be better to send the emails when the exception is posted to application insights but I don't know if that is possible? If that is not possible a scheduled job would be a solution. When I used I created an alert it didn't send any information other than that exceptions had been thrown it did not the include stacktrace I would like to have to be able to quickly analyze the nature of the problem.

Comment: @Tiny-wa: it seems that your rule does provide some detail of the exception. I would be happy if you shared how you created the rule or some link that describes how to create it.

Comment: @mortb Thanks for your response sir, and I've post the details on my steps of creating alert rule. That's meet my requirement, and hope it helpful to you.

Comment: @mortb: Yes, it is possible to generate emails from exceptions that are generated during processing. That has the advantage of avoiding filtering of data and the time lag associated with having the exception logged to Application Insights and then polling AI for the logged exceptions. But this approach assumes that you are able to access the applicable code and make those changes to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a java program, so I used java-appinsights-agent to collect metrics, requests, traces and send them to azure application insights instance. If you used other programming language, microsoft also provides other sdk or solutions.

[image]

I can provide suggestions on it if you needed. And let's start to create an alert rule here. You can also see [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log).

After setting the monitor to my program, I have my application insights instance which provides log analytics. Come to azure portal->your application insights instance-> logs, and let's focus on the exception. As we can see the screenshot below, app insights has caught exception message from my project. I queried all the exceptions here, it's supported to add some filters. Then I click `New alert rule`.

[image]

Next is setting the alert logic, any exception is important for me and I wanna know it as soon as possible, so if the query returns any exception(number of result > 0), the alert rule should be triggered, and the minimum interval for monitoring is 5 minutes here.

[image]

Next is adding action group, I'd like to create a new action group for my project, Add action groups-> create action group

[image]

After entering field in basic panel, let's focus on the Notification, see screenshot below:

[image]

At last, fill some field related to this rule and click create. Then I can receive email like the screenshot in the comment.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't give me the exception detail, just resume that there is a log

Answer (score 3):

I am using application insights for logging but combined with NLog for exception logging to a database and immediate emails with stacktrace.  I could not get timely alerts from application insights for exceptions.